Extract adjacent raster pixels file
I have two burned area raster files in R. I want to find and extract the pixels spatially connected to the previous year's burned area. Hereafter, I want to extract all the pixels spatially connected to the current year's burned area if they were connected to the previous year's burned area.
Code
library(terra)
dnbr14 = vrt("path/dnbr14.tif")
dnbr15 = vrt("path/dnbr15.tif")

# Create a binary raster indicating dNBR14 pixels (1 for dNBR14, 0 for others)
dNBR14_binary <- dNBR14 > 0

# Use focal function to identify adjacent burn pixels
adjacent_burn <- focal(dnbr14, w = matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 3),
                       fun = function(x) {any(x == 0 & dnbr15[] > 0)})

But this does not seem to work.
How can I retrieve (1) the dNBR15 pixels adjacent to the dNBR14 pixels and hereafter all the dNBR15 pixels adjacent to each other from the newly made raster of adjacent dNBR15 and dNBR14 pixels?
Here is the data:
dNBR14
dNBR15
Here is an image of what I need to be extracted.


Any chance to recreate this with minimal SpatRaster objects from scratch? Or at least share your dnbr*.tif raster data to make this reproducible?

I have added some test data, thanks.

Okay I think this is what you are trying to do. I'm adding a couple of extra non-zero cells to your "15" data to create a disconnected patch for testing:
library(terra)
dnbr14 = vrt("dNBR14.tif")
dnbr15 = vrt("dNBR15.tif")

## add a disconnected patch
dnbr15[11,10]=.26
dnbr15[12,10]=.26
dnbr15[12,11]=.26
image(dnbr15)


Next, make the "14" data binary and do a focal which returns if any cell in 14 or its 8-neighbours are equal to 1. Note this doesn't care about "15" yet, its purely a map of where "14" was one or adjacent to a 1. Plot it over the original binary data so we can see what we're getting.
## make 1/0
dnbr14_1 <- dnbr14 > 0

## find all cells at or adjacent to a 1 in dnbr14
dnbr14_nn <- focal(dnbr14_1, w = matrix(1,nrow=3, ncol=3),
                   fun = function(x){any(x==1)})

image(dnbr14_1)
image(dnbr14_nn, add=TRUE, col="#80808080")


Let's see how that overlaps "15":
## how does that relate to non-zero in dnbr15? 
image(dnbr15 > 0 )
image(dnbr14_nn, add=TRUE, col="#80808080")


Which shows what we want out is the two largest patches and not the small patch which I added in bottom right.
The patches function returns 1 to N (in this case 3) for contiguous patches. Run it on "15":
## label contiguous patches 1 to n (3 in this case)
dnbr15_patches = patches(dnbr15)
plot(dnbr15_patches)


Then intersect the focal neighbours with the patch numbers and pull out the unique set of patch cell numbers:
patchnums = unique(dnbr15_patches[(intersect(dnbr15_patches, dnbr14_nn))][,1])

patchcells = dnbr15_patches %in% patchnums
plot(patchcells)


And you can see it has only selected cells from patches that had cells over or adjacent to cells in "14" that were one, and the patch at bottom right is not selected.

Thank you a lot!! I have also worked my way towards this solution. One question arises: the patches function takes much time for all my data. Can I somehow tell it to skip all na.rm or focus on the cells with data?

Not sure - feel free to ask a new question with more details, including the size of your data. It may be that if it has thousands of patches that it will be slow, and maybe there's a way to speed it up or possibly there's another function in another package somewhere that's faster...

Not sure about the efficiency of my take using real-world data, i.e. larger rasters, but when dealing with spatial relations between binary masks, I rather thought of vector operations instead of an pure raster approach - even though this includes some back-and-fort conversions and additional package dependencies, whereas the vector handling can be done without using {sf} maybe.
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# read data
dNBR15 <- rast("dnbr15.tif")
dNBR14 <- rast("dnbr14.tif")

# adding the same addtional disconnected patch as @Spacedman
dNBR15[11,10] <- 0.26
dNBR15[12,10] <- 0.26
dNBR15[12,11] <- 0.26

# create binary masks
dNBR15_binary <- dNBR15 > 0
dNBR14_binary <- dNBR14 > 0

# convert SpatRaster to SpatVector, convert to sf, cast MULTIPOLYGONs to POLYGONs
dNBR15_vect <- as.polygons(dNBR15_binary) |> st_as_sf() |> st_cast("POLYGON")
dNBR14_vect <- as.polygons(dNBR14_binary) |> st_as_sf() |> st_cast("POLYGON")

# which features of `dNBR15_vect` are touched by `dNBR14_vect`?
ind <- st_touches(dNBR14_vect, dNBR15_vect) |> unlist()

# select `dNBR15_vect` based on index determined, add attribute, convert back to SpatVector
v <- dNBR15_vect[ind, ] |> dplyr::mutate(adjacent = TRUE) |> vect()

# rasterize adjacent `dNBR15_vect` features to original raster
r <- rasterize(v, dNBR15, field = "adjacent")

# inspect
plot(r)


Created on 2024-05-09 with reprex v2.1.0
